# React post request with Required request body content is missing

Tags: reactjs, post

I am trying to make a post API call, to send the request, I have to send a body with it, but no matter what I try it did not seem to work. I am using redux saga to send the request.
Here is the error message:

```
{
  "errors": [{
    "message": "Required request body content is missing",
    "reason": "missing",
    "subject": "body",
    "subjectType": "parameter",
    "type": "ValidationError"
  }]
}
```

in my api js files I have:

```
export const postrequest = wrapFunc((data) => hybrisGo({
  url: 'my-url-link',
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
 }));
```

I was thinking maybe the data did not pass through, so I tried to coly the whole object I have for the body to put in the `JSON.stringify()` function, but same error persist.
It is working on postman with no issue, I dont think it requires any headers or anything. Please help, or need more information about my saga file, I can post it, but data did get to pass through it.

Update:
here is my saga file, something like this:

```
try {
    while (true) {
      const action = yield take(actionTypes.POST_SOMETHING);
      const {
        response,
        error
      } = yield call(postrequest, action.data);
      if (response && !error) {
        yield put({
          type: actionTypes.POST_SOMETHING_SUCCESS,
          payload: response.data
        });
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({
      type: actionTypes.POST_SOMETHING_FAILURE,
      payload: e.toString()
    });
  }
```

Comment: how did you call **postrequest** within your component?

Comment: I updated some more code from the saga